# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' when installing via pip3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Python 3 on macOS and got the following error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

I had tried with `pip3 install selenium` but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Comment: python3 -m pip install selenium